# R count the number of occurrences of a specific value within each column of dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

This seems like a really basic question but I can't find a solution that will do what I want for all columns of a dataframe.

I have a dataframe:

```
df = data.frame(cats = c("A", "B", "C", NA, NA), dogs = c(-99, "F", NA, -99, "H"))
```

Where I want to count the number of times NA occurs within each column. I also want to count the number of times -99 occurs within each column. I am able to use summarise_all to count the number of NAs per column.

```
df %>% summarise_all(~ sum(is.na(.)))
```

Which produces the desired result:

```
  cats dogs
  2    1
```

But I can't figure out how to adapt this to count the number of times -99 appears per column. I've tried the following:

```
df %>% summarise_all(~ sum(-99))
```

Which produces this result:

```
  cats dogs
  -99  -99
```

This result shows -99 for each column, even though it never occurs within cats, and it doesn't produce the number of times -99 occurs. There must be an easy way to do this? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Also, take in account that `sumarise_all` is being deprecated in favour of `df %>% summarise(across(everything(), ~ sum(. == -99, na.rm=T)))`

Answer (score 1):

You almost get there, you need to use `na.rm = TRUE` inside `sum`

```
> df %>% summarise_all(~ sum(.== -99, na.rm = TRUE))
  cats dogs
1    0    2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `base R`

```
colSums(df == -99, na.rm = TRUE)
cats dogs 
   0    2
```